# Record can't be indexed when use generic and union type

Tags: typescript

Consider following code.

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noImplicitOverride=true&ts=5.2.0-dev.20230624#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nAPAaShAHsCA7AJgZyn2ACcBLbAcwBooAVNTHAqAJQgGM4TcVbjyVAHxCoAXigBvAFBQoAawgh8ALijJZUAG4BDADYBXCGrrSAvtOmhIUAILjYCRAHIdzgD7OARs9qTXzmrOtr5Q3oHOAELOZkJW4NAAwg7wSM4cHs64of4ZQYmhWREAIjFx8TaRcMAAFg627omWAGYG2BzAZHDYUF46JIgMGFh4hFW1QgAUuBDNJgDazrqGEM4AurSKIAvOW-jrAJRSmgD0J-QJYXTzAER7N2vOUBw62NjVvdAG+BC4UMBwKAUGbof6XZzXG7LIwPZwAOkmACYAKwAZgAbAdNCQIMADCQejNmvMtmsANzmIA)

```js
type Foo<K extends string, T extends Record<K, string>> = {
  keys: K
  value: T
}

type A = Foo<'a'|'b', {'a': 'A', 'b':'B'}>
type C = Foo<'c'|'d', {'c': 'C', 'd':'D'}>

type Both = A|C

// If change to <T extends A> or <T extends C>, it works
function bar<T extends Both>(def: T['value'], key: T['keys']) {
  // Type 'T["keys"]' cannot be used to index type 'T["value"]'.(2536)
  return def[key];
}
```

The `T['value']` do be index by `T['key']` but ts complain it's not allowed.

Why this strange behavior happens? Could you provide a correct snippet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you setup your generics correctly TypeScript simply isn't capable of inferring these indexed types. You'll have to excplicitely tell the compiler that `key` is a `keyof T['value']`.

```
type Foo<K extends string, T extends Record<K, string>> = {
  keys: K
  value: T
}

type A = Foo<'a'|'b', {'a': 'A', 'b':'B'}>
type C = Foo<'c'|'d', {'c': 'C', 'd':'D'}>

type Both = A | C

function bar<T extends Both>(def: T['value'], key: T['keys']) {
  return def[key as keyof T['value']]
}
```

---

If you don't want to use Type Assertion just directly use the `keyof` on your second parameter

```
type Foo<K extends string, T extends Record<K, string>> = {
  keys: K
  value: T
}

type A = Foo<'a'|'b', {'a': 'A', 'b':'B'}>
type C = Foo<'c'|'d', {'c': 'C', 'd':'D'}>

type Both = A|C

function bar<T extends Both>(def: T['value'], key: keyof T['value']) {
  // Type 'T["keys"]' cannot be used to index type 'T["value"]'.(2536)
  return def[key];
}
```

Comment: I don't want to do `as`, it's not safe. In my real code, that means I need do `as` everywhere.

Comment: Please take a look at my edit. The thing is I doubt it's possible to do this any different. You'll have to use a `keyof` somewhere. (Please somebody prove me wrong)

Comment: I can't think of anything at the moment besides the `keyof`